# In a shader program, multiplication and subtraction which one is faster?

Tags: shader, gpu, fragment-shader

I am writing a shader program and I want a color to be darker in the most efficient way as possible.

I could multiply the color with a value less than 1 to get it darker or subtract with a small value. Since this will be in a fragment shader part I want to know which one GPU is better at performing.

The intuition would say addition/subtraction are faster than multiplication/division but is that really correct? My guess is that GPU might be optimized for multiplication (and not division?) since there are many multiplication based calculation in common graphic tasks.

Comment: Personally I would like to use multiply since the darkening will be proportional, but this is a mobile game so I need to be careful on the shader especially fragment which will be called on all pixels..

Comment: Note that the shader code will undergo certain optimizations anyhow. Depending on the platform/compiler/OpenGL implementation, certain division/multiplication operations might be converted into bitwise operations. The trivial example is `x*=2` being converted to `x+=x` or `x<<=1`, but it's hard to say whether this will actually be done for the GPU: It will only be done only **if** they are supposed to be faster, and this is something only the compiler/card vendors will know for sure...